# Unable to click on an element in Browser stack

Tags: java, selenium, browserstack

Unable to click on an element in Browser stack Automate. The same code is running successfully in chrome/firefox.

I am using movetoelement of Actions class to click on a particular element..

```
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.getCurrentDriver());
action.moveToElement(dividerPageView.clickDividerDropped).click().perform();
```

Also used Javascript executor but no use.

```
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@title,'Layout Container')]/following-sibling::div[1]"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Please suggest another way we can click on a element which is running headless.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
int items = driver.findelements(by.xpath("YOUR VALUE")).count
if(items == 1) driver.findelement(by.xpath("YOUR VALUE")).click()
```